# Engineering an even faster qsort

Tags: c, sorting, quick-sort, c89

I understand that `C++` STL template `sort` runs faster than `qsort` in C because `qsort` needs to call the comparator multiple times and `C++` makes the code specific to that type. However, `C`'s pre-processor can hack that, too. So I build a test using `qsort`.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf fputc stdout sprintf */
#include <string.h> /* strcmp */
#include <errno.h>  /* errno */
#include <time.h>   /* clock */
#include <ctype.h>  /* toupper */
#include <math.h>   /* pow */

/* Linked with a qsort called qsort_ that acts as a control to test qsort.
 With C89, no inline, one has to optimise to get anything. */
/*#define QSORT_*/



static int int_cmp(const int *const a, const int *const b) {
    return (*a > *b) - (*b > *a);
}
#define SORT_NAME Int
#define SORT_TYPE int
#define SORT_COMPARATOR &int_cmp
#include "Sort.h"
static int int_void_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return int_cmp(a, b);
}
static void int_fill(int *const a) {
    *a = rand();
}



struct Foo {
    int no;
    char name[64];
};
static const size_t foo_name_size = sizeof ((struct Foo *)0)->name;
static int foo_no_cmp(const struct Foo *const a, const struct Foo *const b) {
    return (a->no > b->no) - (b->no > a->no);
}
#define SORT_NAME FooNo
#define SORT_TYPE struct Foo
#define SORT_COMPARATOR &foo_no_cmp
#include "Sort.h"
static int foo_name_cmp(const struct Foo *const a, const struct Foo *const b) {
    return strcmp(a->name, b->name);
}
#define SORT_NAME FooName
#define SORT_TYPE struct Foo
#define SORT_COMPARATOR &foo_name_cmp
#include "Sort.h"
static int foo_void_no_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return foo_no_cmp(a, b);
}
static int foo_void_name_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return foo_name_cmp(a, b);
}
static void foo_fill(struct Foo *const a) {
    const size_t num_chars = 4 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (foo_name_size - 5) + 1);
    size_t i;
    int_fill(&a->no);
    for(i = 0; i < num_chars; i++) {
        a->name[i] = (i ? 'a' : 'A') + rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) * 26;
    }
    a->name[i] = '\0';
}



/* The control -- not going to include this. C89  */
#ifdef QSORT_ /* <-- my */
void
qsort_(void *a, size_t n, size_t es, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *));
#endif /* my --> */

typedef int (*TestFn)(const size_t, double *const);

/* This is messy. */

#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define TEST_FN(NAME, TYPE, FILL, TEST) \
static int CAT(NAME, _test)(const size_t size, double *const p_ms_time) {\
    TYPE *a = malloc(sizeof *a * size); \
    size_t i; \
    clock_t run; \
    if(!a) return 0; \
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) (FILL)(a + i); \
    run = -clock(); \
    (TEST); \
    run += clock(); \
    *p_ms_time = (double)run / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000.0); \
    free(a); \
    return 1; \
}

TEST_FN(int_q, int, int_fill, qsort(a, size, sizeof *a, &int_void_cmp))
TEST_FN(int_s, int, int_fill, IntSort(a, size))
TEST_FN(foo_no_q, struct Foo, foo_fill, \
    qsort(a, size, sizeof *a, &foo_void_no_cmp))
TEST_FN(foo_no_s, struct Foo, foo_fill, FooNoSort(a, size))
TEST_FN(foo_name_q, struct Foo, foo_fill, \
    qsort(a, size, sizeof *a, &foo_void_name_cmp))
TEST_FN(foo_name_s, struct Foo, foo_fill, FooNameSort(a, size))

#ifdef QSORT_ /* <-- my */
TEST_FN(int_m, int, int_fill, qsort_(a, size, sizeof *a, &int_void_cmp))
TEST_FN(foo_no_m, struct Foo, foo_fill, \
    qsort_(a, size, sizeof *a, &foo_void_no_cmp))
TEST_FN(foo_name_m, struct Foo, foo_fill, \
    qsort_(a, size, sizeof *a, &foo_void_name_cmp))
#endif /* my --> */

static const char *const gnu_name   = "sort.gnu";
static const char *const graph_name = "sort.eps";
static const unsigned replicas      = 5;
static const size_t max_elements    = 100000;

int main(void) {
    struct TimeData { const char *const name; TestFn fn; } time_data[] = {
        { "qsort int", &int_q_test },
        { "IntSort", &int_s_test },
        { "qsort foo::no", &foo_no_q_test },
        { "FooNoSort", &foo_no_s_test },
        { "qsort foo::name", &foo_name_q_test },
        { "FooNameSort", &foo_name_s_test }
#ifdef QSORT_ /* <-- my */
        ,
        { "my qsort_ int", &int_m_test },
        { "my qsort_ foo::no", &foo_no_m_test },
        { "my qsort_ foo::name", &foo_name_m_test }
#endif /* my --> */
    }, *td;
    const size_t time_data_size = sizeof time_data / sizeof *time_data;
    unsigned td_i;
    FILE *fp = 0, *gnu = 0;
    size_t elements, x, r;
    char fn_name[32] = "not a file";
    unsigned seed = (unsigned)clock();
    const char *err = 0;

    srand(seed), rand(), printf("Seed %u.\n", seed);
    do { /* Try. */
        if(!(gnu = fopen(gnu_name, "w"))) { err = gnu_name; break; }
        fprintf(gnu, "set term postscript eps enhanced color\n"
            "set output \"%s\"\n"
            "set grid\n"
            "set xlabel \"array elements\"\n"
            "set ylabel \"processor time, t (ms)\"\n"
            "set yrange [0:]\n"
            "# seed %u\n"
            "\n"
            "plot", graph_name, seed);
        for(td_i = 0; td = time_data + td_i, td_i < time_data_size; td_i++) {
            /* Open <sort>.tsv for writing. */
            if(sprintf(fn_name, "%s.tsv", td->name) < 0
               || !(fp = fopen(fn_name, "w"))) { err = fn_name; break; }
            fprintf(stderr, "Created/overwrote, \"%s,\" to store data on %s "
                "sort.\n", fn_name, td->name);
            /* Do several experiments, increasing number of elements. */
            fprintf(fp, "# %s: elements ms\n", td->name);
            for(elements = 1, x = 2; elements <= max_elements;
                elements = (unsigned)pow((double)x++, 3.5)) {
                int n = 0;
                double dt_ms = 0.0, mean_ms = 0.0, delta_ms, ssdm = 0.0;
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: sorting %lu elements distributed uniformly"
                    " at random.\n", td->name, (unsigned long)elements);
                /* \cite{Welford1962Note} */
                for(r = 0; r < replicas; r++) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "#");
                    if(!td->fn(elements, &dt_ms)) { err = "experiment"; break; }
                    n++;
                    delta_ms = dt_ms - mean_ms;
                    mean_ms += delta_ms / n;
                    ssdm += delta_ms * (dt_ms - mean_ms);
                }
                fprintf(stderr, " done.\n");
                if(r != replicas) break;
                fprintf(fp, "%lu\t%f\t%f\n", (unsigned long)elements, mean_ms,
                    sqrt(ssdm / (n - 1)));
            }
            /* close the file */
            if(fclose(fp)) { fp = 0; err = fn_name; break; }
            fp = 0;
            /* write the graph */
            fprintf(gnu,
                "%s\t\"%s\" using 1:2:3 with errorlines lw 3 title \"%s\"",
                td_i ? ", \\\n" : " ", fn_name, td->name);
        }
        fprintf(gnu, "\n");
    } while(0); if(err) perror(err); /* Catch. */
    { /* Finally. */
        if(fp  && fclose(fp))  perror(fn_name);
        if(gnu && fclose(gnu)) perror(gnu_name);
    }
    return err ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is code taken from [Bentley McIlroy 1993](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/spe.4380231105) and Berkeley; I've modified it to take parameters in the form of pre-processor `#define`s. It must be run with optimisations on since I'm using `C89`: doesn't support `inline`. I've gotten rid of the warnings, but I'm not sure this compiles to the same code.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995 NeXT Computer, Inc. All Rights Reserved
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1992, 1993
 *  The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software
 *    must display the following acknowledgement:
 *  This product includes software developed by the University of
 *  California, Berkeley and its contributors.
 * 4. Neither the name of the University nor the names of its contributors
 *    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 *    without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 *  @(#)qsort.c 8.1 (Berkeley) 6/4/93
 */

/* Modified by Neil to make it parameterised.

 The parameters are preprocessor macros and all are all undefined at the end of
 the file for convenience.

 @param SORT_NAME
 A unique name associated with {<S>} that satisfies {C} naming conventions when
 mangled.

 @param SORT_TYPE
 This type becomes {<S>}; required.

 @param SORT_COMPARATOR
 A function satisfying {<PS>SortComparator}.

 @std C89
 */

/* Check defines. */
#ifndef SORT_NAME
#error Sort name SORT_NAME undefined.
#endif
#ifndef SORT_TYPE
#error Sort type SORT_TYPE undefined.
#endif
#ifndef SORT_COMPARATOR
#error Sort function SORT_COMPARATOR undefined.
#endif

/* Generics using the preprocessor;
 \url{ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522341/pseudo-generics-in-c }. */
#ifdef CAT
#undef CAT
#endif
#ifdef CAT_
#undef CAT_
#endif
#ifdef PCAT
#undef PCAT
#endif
#ifdef PCAT_
#undef PCAT_
#endif
#ifdef S
#undef S
#endif
#ifdef S_
#undef S_
#endif
#ifdef PS_
#undef PS_
#endif
#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define PCAT_(x, y) x ## _ ## y
#define PCAT(x, y) PCAT_(x, y)
#define S_(thing) CAT(SORT_NAME, thing)
#define PS_(thing) PCAT(sort, PCAT(SORT_NAME, thing)) /* Private. */

/* Troubles with this line? check to ensure that {SORT_TYPE} is a valid type,
 whose definition is placed above {#include "Sort.h"}. */
typedef SORT_TYPE PS_(Type);
#define S PS_(Type)

/** Must establish a partial order amongst {<S>} by returning
 {a < b, negative; a = b, 0; a > b, positive}. */
typedef int (*PS_(SortComparator))(const S *const a, const S *const b);
/* Check that {MAP_COMPARATOR} is a function implementing
 {<PS>SortComparator}. */
static const PS_(SortComparator) PS_(cmp) = (SORT_COMPARATOR);



#include <sys/types.h>

#ifndef SORT_H /* <-- h Idempotent. */
#define SORT_H

#define sort_min(a, b) (a) < (b) ? a : b

enum SortSwapType { WORD, WORDS, BYTE };

#endif /* h --> */

/*
 * Qsort routine from Bentley & McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function".
 *
 * (How does that work with the copyright?)
 */

static void
PS_(swapfunc)(S *a, S *b, const size_t n, const enum SortSwapType swaptype)
{
    switch(swaptype) {
    case WORDS:
    case WORD:
        {
            long i = sizeof *a * n / sizeof(long);
            long *pi = (long *)(void *)a;
            long *pj = (long *)(void *)b;
            do {
                long t = *pi;
                *pi++ = *pj;
                *pj++ = t;
            } while (--i > 0);
        }
        break;
    case BYTE:
        {
            long i = sizeof *a * n;
            char *pi = (char *)a;
            char *pj = (char *)b;
            do {
                char t = *pi;
                *pi++ = *pj;
                *pj++ = t;
            } while (--i > 0);
        }
        break;
    }
}

static void
PS_(swap)(S *a, S *b, const enum SortSwapType swaptype)
{
    if(swaptype == WORD) {
        long t = *(long *)(void *)(a);
        *(long *)(void *)(a) = *(long *)(void *)(b);
        *(long *)(void *)(b) = t;
    } else {
        PS_(swapfunc)(a, b, (size_t)1, swaptype);
    }
}

static S *
PS_(med3)(S *a, S *b, S *c)
{
    return PS_(cmp)(a, b) < 0 ?
        (PS_(cmp)(b, c) < 0 ? b : (PS_(cmp)(a, c) < 0 ? c : a ))
        : (PS_(cmp)(b, c) > 0 ? b : (PS_(cmp)(a, c) < 0 ? a : c ));
}

static void
S_(Sort)(S *a, size_t n)
{
    S *pa, *pb, *pc, *pd, *pl, *pm, *pn;
    size_t vec;
    long d;
    enum SortSwapType swaptype;
    int swap_cnt, r;

loop:
    /* Re: (0*n) "warning: use of logical || with constant operand; switch to
     bitwise | or remove constant [-Wconstant-logical-operand]" but sizeof are
     not supported in pre-precessor. :S Wouldn't this be constant? */
    swaptype = ((char *)a - (char *)0) % sizeof(long)
        || sizeof *a % sizeof(long) + (0*n) ? BYTE
        : sizeof *a == sizeof(long) ? WORD : WORDS;
    swap_cnt = 0;
    if (n < 7) {
        for (pm = a + 1; pm < a + n; pm++)
            for (pl = pm; pl > a && PS_(cmp)(pl - 1, pl) > 0; pl--)
                PS_(swap)(pl, pl - 1, swaptype);
        return;
    }
    pm = a + (n / 2);
    if (n > 7) {
        pl = a;
        pn = a + (n - 1);
        if (n > 40) {
            d = n / 8;
            pl = PS_(med3)(pl, pl + d, pl + 2 * d);
            pm = PS_(med3)(pm - d, pm, pm + d);
            pn = PS_(med3)(pn - 2 * d, pn - d, pn);
        }
        pm = PS_(med3)(pl, pm, pn);
    }
    PS_(swap)(a, pm, swaptype);
    pa = pb = a + 1;

    pc = pd = a + (n - 1);
    for (;;) {
        while (pb <= pc && (r = PS_(cmp)(pb, a)) <= 0) {
            if (r == 0) {
                swap_cnt = 1;
                PS_(swap)(pa, pb, swaptype);
                pa++;
            }
            pb++;
        }
        while (pb <= pc && (r = PS_(cmp)(pc, a)) >= 0) {
            if (r == 0) {
                swap_cnt = 1;
                PS_(swap)(pc, pd, swaptype);
                pd--;
            }
            pc--;
        }
        if (pb > pc)
            break;
        PS_(swap)(pb, pc, swaptype);
        swap_cnt = 1;
        pb++;
        pc--;
    }
    if (swap_cnt == 0) { /* Switch to insertion sort */
        for (pm = a + 1; pm < a + n; pm++)
            for (pl = pm; pl > a && PS_(cmp)(pl - 1, pl) > 0; pl--)
                PS_(swap)(pl, pl - 1, swaptype);
        return;
    }

    pn = a + n;
    vec = sort_min(pa - a, pb - pa);
    if(vec > 0) PS_(swapfunc)(a, pb - vec, vec, swaptype);
    vec = sort_min((size_t)(pd - pc), (size_t)(pn - pd - 1));
    if(vec > 0) PS_(swapfunc)(pb, pn - vec, vec, swaptype);
    if ((size_t)(vec = pb - pa) > 1)
        S_(Sort)(a, vec);
    if ((vec = pd - pc) > 1) {
        /* Iterate rather than recurse to save stack space */
        a = pn - vec;
        n = vec;
        goto loop;
    }
}

/* Un-define all macros. Undocumented; allows nestled inclusion so long as:
 {CAT_}, {CAT}, {PCAT}, {PCAT_} conform, and {S}, is not used. */
#ifdef SORT_SUBTYPE /* <-- sub */
#undef SORT_SUBTYPE
#else /* sub --><-- !sub */
#undef CAT
#undef CAT_
#undef PCAT
#undef PCAT_
#endif /* !sub --> */
#undef S
#undef S_
#undef PS_
#undef SORT_NAME
#undef SORT_TYPE
#undef SORT_COMPARATOR
```

On my computer, it outputs, with optimisations on, `via` `gnuplot`. It is faster, but not by much.

[image: As expected, parameterised sort is better then a general qsort.]

I'm not sure about the changes I've made to `qsort.c`. Specifically, why `swaptype = (a-(char*)0 | es) % W ? 2 : es > W ? 1 : 0` ([Bentley1993](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/spe.4380231105),) where `es` is the size. Why is it called every time? Shouldn't it be `a | es` without the subtracting null? Isn't `a` aligned properly and it might be `es` and taken out of the loop?

Comment: you might be interested in [Perl's qsort](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/cc93400aa5a8d556c56c28a8de644bd178d050d4/pp_sort.c) which switches to insertion sort on small partitions.

Comment: I think that they were heavily influenced by the same paper.

Comment: It would be interesting to see where std::sort places on that graph.